# How to use radius style in Flex plot charting

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, charts

When I use radius property in Flex plot chart
It causes a warning says radius has been deprecated, please use radius style
There's no online documents about this warning.
How Can I use radius style ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach would be to experiment with a few different methods... seeing as how adobe has failed to provide examples on their live docs - [PlotSeries](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/series/PlotSeries.html)

For example, you could try:

```
chart.setStyle('radius', 5);
```

Build your project and see what happens...